# Apply button style dynamically

Tags: android, button, styles

I have a little trouble:
I will create dynamically material buttons applying @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless style. Obviously if I create buttons in xml file to static buttons it works fine, but in java code I don't know how do this. This is my code

```
  for (String nameCat : cat){
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        lP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(60)); // dpToPx is convert method
        button.setLayoutParams(lP);

        // text button
        button.setText(nameCat);
        // add to linear layout
        lL.addView(button);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if yu have your style in XML

```
 ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.MyStyle);
    button = new Button(newContext);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'll try. Do you know where can I find @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless file?